# How can I have known current font encoding?

Tags: font-encodings

How can I have known current font encoding? I know that a list of font encodings is saved in 
`\cdp@list` macro. Last element of `\cdp@list` is usually the effective encoding but this is not always true; for example, `\setlanguage` might switch current encoding.

Actually, I want to distinguish the case where either EU1 or EU2 font encoding is in effect from a non-unicode encoding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The macro `\f@encoding` always expands to the current encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printenc}{the current encoding is~\texttt{\f@encoding}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text in English: \printenc

\foreignlanguage{russian}{Какой-то осмысленный текст: \printenc}

English again: \printenc

\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}
Какой-то осмысленный текст: \printenc
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As far as XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are concerned, the encoding should always be `EU1` or `EU2`, respectively, unless you're mixing fonts, which is not recommended.

Comment: Nowadays, the default encoding used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec` is `TU`.

Comment: Indeed, since 2017, as announced in the LaTeX News: https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews26.pdf.